# Edit "From" field in outlook using @mailto

Tags: javascript, email, xslt, mailto

Is it possible to add/change the "From" field using "mailto:" template?
Need to add some default sender email address using this "mailto:"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is impossible. Link `mailto:` opening sofware to send e-mail. User logged in that software is automatically sender.

You can only change other parameters.

[image]

Example href:

```
mailto:person@example.com?subject=The%20subject&amp;body=This%20is%20a%20message%20body
```

Comment: Thanks @Dave, I understand now.